# How should particle names ending in -on be treated in Latin?

Tags: etymology, contemporary-latin, science

There are many particle names ending in -on in English: electron, muon, lepton, proton…
How should these particle names behave in Latin?

My impression is that the electron and the proton came first (I'm not sure of their naming order), and the rest were modeled on them.
The electron is "amber" (*ἤλεκτρον*) and proton is "first" (*πρῶτον*).
This makes me want to treat all these particles of second declension neuters of the Greek type, and I wouldn't be opposed to Latinizing them into *electrum* and *protum* if someone is so inclined.

However, [Vicipaedia](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron) seems to treat these words as third declension masculines ending in *-on/-onis*.
This feels off to me, especially with the final *-n* which I expect to be dropped from a Latin nominative of this kind.
The Latin Wikipedia is not particularly reliable, but there might be a good reason for this convention.
Perhaps the words were borrowed from English to Latin and assigned to the third declension without much etymological thought.
Or this might be by analogy to Italian where the ending is -one (corresponding to the Latin third declension).

Etymological considerations and comparison with Italian seem lead to different Latin declensions.
Vicipaedia also gives the alternative *electronium*.
Yet another thing to consider is that the neutron might have a significant conflict with the pronoun *neuter*.

How do you think the particle names ending in -on in English should be treated in Latin?
And, most importantly, why so?

Comment: The -on/-onis ending seems off to me too. I'd have thought electrum, protum, etc. would be the most obvious Latin forms. Perhaps it's merely to distinguish the word for electron from the word for amber, and then the other particles are named by analogy. I'm not sure that's a very compelling reason though; after all, how often does the word amber really come up? On a whim, I checked what the modern Greek words for electron and proton are, to see whether they've also been distinguished from the words for amber and first. Sure enough: ηλεκτρόνιο and πρωτόνιο, which I assume are diminutive forms.

Comment: @cnread Vicipaedia also gives the alternative *electronium* (which I only now remembered to add to the question). Many words have several different meanings, and the risk of confusing electrons with amber is minimal. If it seems to be a problem in some situation, one can always add words to clarify. I wonder if the suggestions in Vicipaedia are borrowed from (written by native speakers of?) Italian or Greek. I feel it's best to go directly from the Greek origin to Latin without passing through modern languages, but others might disagree.

Comment: Based on cursory (*cough* Etymonline *cough*) research, the "-on" in electron is by analogy with "ion," which itself is merely a transliteration ἰών, the present participle of Greek "to go." In that case, it would be misguided to act as if -on was a neuter 2nd declension ending. I found an old book called *De iontum migrationibus electrolyticis* to confirm that at least one person thought that way...

Comment: The rule on Vicipædia is "[noli fingere](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vicipaedia:Noli_fingere)": they want a source or precedent for every word. Are you able to check the sources given in the Vicipædia article? (They're at the bottom in small type under Notae.)

Comment: @BenKovitz It's good to know they have that guideline; I hope they adhere to it, too. Having the different variations in dictionaries is indeed evidence to support them, but it would be good to know (and that would constitute an answer here) on what grounds the particular version was chosen for a dictionary. I can check the cited Finnish dictionary, but not soon.

Comment: @brianpck Oh, I didn't know that electron was modeled on ion. (I assumed "electron" was a direct Greek loan without any analogy to other words, whence the second declension seemed most natural.) If that is indeed the case, that would make a good answer. I'm not sure at all how to most fluently latinize the Greek participle. Perhaps *-ōn*, *-ōns*, *-ō*, or *-ēns*? One complication is that if I remember correctly, it took some time to settle on a single variant of the particle names in the original language(s) too.

Comment: Based on @brianpck's book title, the particle names would be Greek active participles, which in Latin would probably be rendered with _-on, -ontis_ (as in _Xenophon_)

Comment: ...or the Latin suffix aequivalent to Greek *-iont-* is in fact the common suffix *-ion-*. // As to the origin of modern *electron*, I would expect it to be derived from the word(s) *electricity* and *electric(al)* — which are no doubt older — and then modelled on the modern word *ion* by analogy. I would not expect a direct derivation from Greek *elektron*.

Comment: -on (-ον) termination in Ancient Greek (not Modern) refers to the neuter of second declination, so it would be appropriate to translate it with the neuter of Latin's second declination. Said this you would be right translating "proton" as "protum", "electron" as "electrum" and so on. It is also right keeping Greek names not declinable like "fas", "nefas", "instar",...
I wouldn't track the word till Italian language because since it's vulgar and romance language is different from Latin: for example the word "electron" in Italian is "elettrone", but the word "apeiron" is still "apeiron"

Comment: @Cerberus I had imagined "electricity" was derived from "electron", but perhaps that's indeed false. But it could have been that by the time the "electricity particle" needed to be named, people looked into the etymology and went with the underlying Greek word directly. [The Wikipedia page on the etymology of electricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymology_of_electricity) doesn't really tell about electrons at all. I'm more and more puzzled, but also happier and happier that I asked this question...

Comment: @dulindraxe The question seems to be, to some extent at least, whether we should treat the word "electron" as coming from the Greek *ἤλεκτρον* directly or if there was something else.

Comment: **Everyone:** There are very good observations and nice ideas in the comments. **Please write your ideas into answers.** An answer does not have to be perfect to be useful. I would much like to have the different ideas posted as answers, so that people can vote, comment, and develop the ideas further.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is correct that ἤλεκτρον means “gold-silver alloy”, and then “amber”, and that it is the source of modern words like electricity, electric, electromagnetism etc. But I do not think you can say that “electron” is borrowed directly from ἤλεκτρον, especially as it does not have the same meaning. Rather it is a modern formation with the “particle” suffix -on. This started with the genuine Greek words anion “going up” and kation “going down”, both neuter participles of the verb “to go” with different prefixes: an- and kat(a)-. Then we got “ion” on its own as a term encompassing both, and then, by analogy, “proton”, “electron”, “neutron”, and ultimately also “positron” (the last of these based on a spurious reanalysis of electr-on as elect-ron, and creation of a pseudo-suffix “ron”).

So what to do in (Neo-)Latin? Perhaps reborrow the English “electron” as electron, -ontis?

Comment: Recycling my answer to a similar question in the "History of Science" forum: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/643/where-did-the-naming-structure-of-particles-come-from-suffix-on/646#646

Comment: Interesting (albeit noisy) discussion: https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disputatio:Particula_elementaria

Answer (score 4):

To add another voice to this conversation, I would like to show the entries given for various particles in the [Morgan and Silva Furman University Lexicon](https://ia801000.us.archive.org/12/items/TheLexiconAnglumEtLatinumByDavidMorgan/MorganAndSilvaFurmanUniversityLexicon.pdf):

> electron- *electron, -onis; electronium, -i*
>
> proton- *protonium -i*
>
> neutron- *neutro, -onis; neutronium, -i*
>
> anti-neutron- *antineutronium*
>
> anti-proton- *antiprotonium*
>
> photon- *photonium*
>
> quark- *quarcium*

For the most part, there seems to be a trend of adding *-ium* to the end of the particle's English name. Many of these words are source to the Latinitas Recens, so it seems somewhat credible. However, as for electron and neutron, there seems to also exist alternative forms that retain the more Greek origins. fdb suggests in their answer that the genitive form for this would be *-ontis,* however, this seems to be refuted by these entries, which drop the t. Joonas Ilmavirta makes a good point about how some of these terms may be confusing when one starts talking about other similarly named objects, but I feel as though, to use his example, protonium would not be translated as such. In the Wikipedia article he cites, it states that the other name for this particle is anti-protonic hydrogen. Perhaps this could instead be translated as *antiprotonicum hydrogenium*. Note here that even hydrogen follows the *-ium* rule.

It seems that there is evidence for *-ium* as the preferred ending to particles. However, there is still much to be discussed in the matter, as demonstrated by the many comments and answers to this question.

---

A few final notes:

1. There are a few deviants to this pattern that I found, one of which was already discussed:

> ion- *ion, iontis*
>
> neon- *neon, neoni*

I'm not sure what to make of that, but I guess that's for you to figure out.

2. Even in classical Latin there are examples of words that look exactly the same, and yet have different meanings. Although attempts should be made to avoid this moving forward, it is something we still have to deal with if it does occur. Just one example:

> *avis*
>
> - nominative or genitive singular meaning bird
> - dative or ablative plural meaning grandmothers/fathers

Obviously, the meaning could probably be deduced from context, and I think a similar line of thought could be used when talking about possible conflicts. So those are my two cents, do with that what you will!

Comment: From the point of view of a chemist, this would be somewhat confusing. The "ium" ending is associated with elements, not particles.

Comment: @RayButterworth No reason it couldn't be both? This is Latin, after all, not English. There are plenty of Latin nouns ending in -ium that aren't elements.

Comment: @cmw, it *can* be whatever it is. I'm just saying that chemistry has a naming convention, and this eliminates it. It's like "-ase" means enzyme, "-ose" means sugar, "-ol" means alcohol, "-ic acid" means fatty acid, etc. The conventions aren't necessary, but they *are* convenient.

Answer (score 4):

My understanding is that the mother of all *-on* scientific terms is the *ion*, which is a Greek neuter participle (I'm told). Later -on coinings seem to be a play on the already understood word *ion*. Its natural Latinization, it seems to me, would be *ion*, *iontis*.

Mutatis mutandis, then, the genitives of your list of words would be *electrontis*, *muontis*, *leptontis*, *protontis*, etc.

Answer (score 2):

There are reasons to treat them as (Greek style) second declension neuters.
The Latin ending corresponding to the Greek *-on* is *-um*, and the names can be Latinized as *electrum* etc.

There was no word for an electron in Greek or any other language.
One simply had to come up with a new word or borrow a word from a classical language and change the meaning — the latter method was certainly not unheard of in science.
Picking *ἤλεκτρον* for the name of a negatively charged particle makes sense.
Similarly *πρῶτον* can be chosen for the name of a positively charged particle.

These two words are second declension neuters in Greek, and are easily recognized as such.
(Yes, *πρῶτον* has masculine and feminine words too, but the neuter forms are regular second declension.)
Therefore it is most intuitive to treat them similarly as Latin words.

Similarity to the Greek participle *ion* may be seen as an accident.
I see no problem declining *ion* as *iontis* while using the genitive *electri* for *electron*.

I would strongly advise against using forms like *electronium*, since there are established physical concepts with names like [protonium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protonium).
When confusion can be avoided, it should.

Answer (score 2):

A contrarian suggestion: recall the conference in 1932 where two kinds of “neutron” were discussed, and Fermi said (in Italian) “let's call the heavy one *neutrone* and the little one *neutrino*,” suggesting that he at least fancifully feigned to understand *–one* as the augmentative suffix, which in Latin is *–ō, –ōnis*.

Comment: The Italian *-one* does seem to come from the Latin *-o*, but did it have an augmentative sense in Latin? See [this question on augmentatives in Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/8804/79) for details.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Well there's the bignosed poet Publius Ovidius Naso.  As a student I took that as ablative “with the nose” … unfortunately Latin Wikipedia does not provide stems for its lemmata :(

Answer (score 2):

I will post some arguments in support of the *electrōn, electrōnis* (m.) convention.

- It seems to effectively avoid ambiguity for most forms: *electrōn, electrōnis, electrōnī, electrōnem, electrōne, electrōnēs, electrōnum, electrōnibus.* [Ray Butterworth](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4454/how-should-particle-names-ending-in-on-be-treated-in-latin#comment44605_4487) and [Joonas](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/4472/9) point out that the versions ending in *-ōnium,* *-ōniī*, such as *prōtōnium,* may cause semantic confusion with other terms that have different meanings. Using second-declension neuter versions, such as *electron, electrī,* leads as Joonas mentioned to ambiguity between many forms of *neutron* and of *neuter, neutra, neutrum,* which seems undesirable.
- It seems more straightforward and less "fanciful" in my view than using the participial declension in *-on, -ontis.* (I don't feel strongly averse to using stems in *-ont-* for particle names, but to me it feels like it has a bit of the flavor of using "octopodes" as the plural of "octopus" in English.)

My response to the objection that Latin third-declension nouns do not usually have a nominative form ending in *-ōn* is that this is not an inviolable rule, but simply the norm that historically developed for native Latin words. Words borrowed from foreign languages were often adapted to the Latin pattern, but not invariably so. Given that for most people living today, the most familiar forms of these particle names (and related words such as *electronic*) feature an ending containing the letter N, it seems preferable to me to retain this letter rather than removing it when using the names in Latin. We can view it as a borrowing into Latin from modern scientific terminology. Even if this creates a somewhat unusual declension pattern, it is at any rate not an entirely unprecedented paradigm: compare *[Babylōn, Babylōnis](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/Babylon)* (f.) and [*Calydōn, Calydōnis*](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/Calydon) (f.).

I think clarity and recognizability are more important and more achievable goals in this context than etymological accuracy.

Many of the advantages I mentioned apply also to similar third-declension variants, such as *electrōn, electronis* (modeled, rather arbitrarily, after the paradigm of *canōn, canonis*) or *electrō, electrōnis.*

Comment: Just to be sure: Is a third declension version of the original Greek *electron* attested? It does make some sense to divorce from etymology in favor of unified and practical particle names, but maybe that statement should be made explicit.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta: As fdb said, the particle name "electron" seems to not have any original Ancient Greek form, because it was coined in the modern era as a blend of "electric" and "ion". The Oxford English Dictionary actually has two separate entries for *electron* n² (the particle name) and *electron* n¹ (electrum, the mix of gold and silver = ἤλεκτρον).

Answer (score 0):

In my [YouTube video about afterlife in Latin](https://youtube.com/watch?v=gx1hhczsdAE&feature=share), I used "*particulae electricitatis*" for "*electron*":

> Multi homines huius temporis dicunt physica quantorum arguere pro vita post mortem. Sed ego censeo physica quantorum arguere contra vitam post mortem. Si non contra omnes formas vitae post mortem, tunc contra formam vitae post mortem in quam plurimi homines credunt. Plurimi homines imaginantur animas, et ut eae animae quodam modo possint videre, sed eae animae non possint videri ab aliquibus machinis. Sed physica quantorum docet nobis quod passivi observatores non dantur. **Particulae electricitatis** agunt ut undae cum non spectantur, sed eae agunt ut particulae cum spectantur. Si animae existunt quae possunt videre, eae animae possint videri ab aliquibus machinis. Ergo, forma vitae post mortem, in quam plurimi homines credunt, ea contradicit firmissimae scientiae, quae est physica quantorum. Ego censeo solum modum, quod eam problemam evitat, monades Gottfriedis Leibnizis sunt. Gottfried Leibniz enim censebat rem extensam et rem cogitantem non interagere, sed solummodo apparere interagere. Sane, novacula Occami tunc arguit contra existentiam rei cogitantis.

I think that's the phrasing that's the least likely to cause a confusion.

Comment: Thanks! This is a useful circumlocution for some contexts, but in physics a "particle of electricity" would be ambiguous. When there is an electric current, the particles that move are not always electrons, and in my first reaction to the term would be a photon, the carrier of the electromagnetic force. But I know full well that I'm biased as a physicist, and many others will react to the term differently.

Answer (score -2):

Greek names like Platon, Oxford Platonis opera, Ion, Charon, Kimon, Jason with were so common in the Latin speaking world, so there is no need to introduce something else like protium or photium as  given names by the fathers of the elementary particle world.

The chemical world consists of -iums, mostly to denote substantial orgin as in sodium (from German Soda, German natrium from french/engl. natron, arabic from gr. nitron)  or personal origin as eg. in Curium.

Comment: The ending *-on* (and especially the inflected forms) in the Greek words *Platon* and *electron* are different. If I'm interpreting your answer correctly (which may or may not be the case), you seem to be conflating the two *-on* endings. How would you decline the word *electron* in Latin? *Electri* or *electronis* in the genitive?

Comment: In quantum statistics all elementary particles of the same 'name' are indistinguishable. Any of those invisible little entities called elementary particle has a counterpart, its antiparticle. Feynman ascribed to them that they move backwards in time, perhaps a mathematical trick. So he proposed, that there is only one single electron and one single proton in the whole universe of which we observe different parts of its trace. Conclusion: the electron as a name may be different from its greek origin, a silver-gold gold mixture, that would translate into electronium by Latin writing chemists.