# How is 'holon'(ὅλον)(philosophy word) different from 'whole' in Greek?

Tags: ancient-greek, greek-to-english-translation

[Philosophy word 'Holon'(in English)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holon_(philosophy)) is translated to 'ὅλον' in Greek as the wikipedia page says.

On the other side, ['Whole'(in English)](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0052%3Abook%3D5%3Asection%3D1023b) is also tanslated to [ὅλον](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0051%3Abook%3D5%3Asection%3D1023b) at Aristotle's Metaphysics.

Philosophy world 'Holon' (in English) is apparently different from 'Whole'; Holon means both whole and part simultaneously.

I wonder how Arthur Koestler's books about Holon are translated into Greek to differentiate 'holon' from 'whole'.

Comment: I think you would be better suited to ask this on the Philosophy StackExchange, as the main part of the question is the meaning of the philosophical term. If you question is about translations of the philosophical term into Greek, then it is a question about Modern Greek which isn't suited for this site.

Comment: @dbmag9 Thank you for your suggestion! My question is to avoid ambiguity between Kestler's term 'HOLON' and Greek word "ὅλον'".  I think Kestler's 'HOLON' should be original term, but the English wikipedia page leads a confution that HOLON is "ὅλον" in Greek (= 'whole' ), but whole is apprently not HOLON, so I wonder how Kestler's HOLON is translated into Greek actually.  In this case, do you recommend Philosophy StackExchange is a better site?, Or, could you let me know where is Modern Greek Q&A site (or my tag "ancient-greek" should be changed to "greek" or "modern-greek")?

Comment: Are you seeking to write about this area of philosophy in Greek, or just interested in how to use the term in English?

Comment: I would like to correct wrong definition of HOLON(philosphy) page of Japanese wikipedia, which says HOLON = "ὅλον'".  What I wrote at above my comment was wrong (English HOLON wikipedia page says holon  = Greek "ὅλον").  Sorry for confusing you.  The English page actually says HOLON = whole + part (Greek:  "ὅλον" + "ον").  I agree with this definition.  Now, I am curious that HOLON = "ὅλονον" in Greek If this English definition is right?  Why I'm confirming the meaning of HOLON in Greek is to correct Japanse wikipedia page.

Answer (score 3):

"A holon (Greek: ὅλον, from ὅλος, holos, 'whole' and -ον, -on, 'part') is something that is simultaneously a whole in and of itself, as well as a part of a larger whole." Thus sayeth Wikipedia. But this is nonsense. "Holon" is the neuter singular of "holos"; it means "a whole thing".

This is perhaps also of interest: [How should particle names ending in -on be treated in Latin?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4454/how-should-particle-names-ending-in-on-be-treated-in-latin)

Comment: Wouldn't be the first time philosophers took an ordinary word and gave it a technical meaning with only a tenuous connection to its everyday meaning. (Mathematicians are even worse about this.)

Answer (score 3):

fdb's answer is entirely correct, but to put it another way:

The word ὅλον (*holon*), in Ancient Greek, just means "whole"—specifically the neuter singular nominative or accusative form. It's a pretty common word and has nothing to do with simultaneously being a part.

Arthur Koestler then used the word for a very different meaning in his books, writing in English, millennia later. But this is an English usage, not an Ancient Greek one. It's somewhat like how the Latin word *id* just means "it", not the primal instincts buried in the human psyche, or the Greek word ἤλεκτρον (*ēlectron*) means "amber" or "electrum", not a subatomic particle. Taking an Ancient Greek or Latin word and giving it a new, specific, technical meaning is a long and glorious tradition—and it's generally less confusing than repurposing an English word that the audience will already have in their mental lexicon.